# VIsual Studio Code Plain Text Files

Tags: visual-studio-code, text

I have been searching for over 30 minutes but can't find the solution. On my Windows installation of VSCode when I create a new file (default to Plain Text as expected) and I go to save, it defaults to saving with a .txt extension. On my Mac though it defaults to All Files. I have searched through settings and I don't recall changing anything on my Windows machine but I WANT to save new files that are Plain Text with .txt by default on Mac.  What am I missing?

Comment: why don't you create new files with the **New File** button in the Explorer or with the context menu in Explorer

Comment: It's just a convenience thing.  I am old school and use .txt files for notes and such (not a markdown fan). I can specify the file extension for sure but not sure why it can't just default on Mac setup. Works for other file types (javascript, python) but not plain text (.txt)

Comment: you create a `foobar.txt` (give an extension) file and the languageId is not `plaintext`